How can I commit a de facto .devcontainer folder while still allowing customization?
I would like to create a .devcontainer folder with the json definition and Dockerfile and commit it to my repository to be the de facto development environment. However, I understand folks like to customize and want to accommodate modifications to the environment. (adding to the extensions list, different run args, etc.)
Folks could modify the .devcontainer.json or Dockerfile directly, but then they risk committing their mods. I thought I might be able to add these to .gitignore after committing, but git still tracks them.

If you are talking about maintainers or people on your team, you can use a template repository and have them use that whenever they plan to edit your project. If they want to modify it, they can fork it and use that forked version.
Another possibility is that you specify multiple dev container configurations to give choices when opening your project in a container.

If you want to have a choice of dev container configurations in your repository, any alternatives to the  .devcontainer/devcontainer.json (or .devcontainer.json) file must be located in their own subdirectory at the path .devcontainer/SUBDIRECTORY/devcontainer.json. For example, you could have a choice of two configurations:

.devcontainer/database-dev/devcontainer.json
.devcontainer/gui-dev/devcontainer.json


